# What is difference between magento-1.9 and ce-1.9.0.1?

Tags: discussion

In this site there are two tag magento-1.9 and ce-1.9.0.1.

Both tag is show  which community edition you are using in magento.

so what is difference between this that i can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issue has been resolved at 1.9.0.1

- `Customers can no longer apply a coupon from an inactive shopping` cart
  `price rule to a purchase`.
- `Customers using a smartphone or other small viewport can expand
  subcategories in the web store that uses the new responsive theme.`

See details at release [note](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1901)